# Does the UK have non-driver license photo ID cards?

Tags: united-kingdom, england-and-wales, any-jurisdiction, identification

Alice doesn’t drive and doesn’t desire to obtain a passport, however she would like to have a photo ID with which to (for example) buy alcohol.

Can she obtain from DVLA (or any other body) an official photo ID card that she can use to prove her identity as a non-driver?

Comment: There was a government-issued ID card program that was scrapped after a fairly short time, maybe 10 or 15 years ago.  I'm not sure any were ever issued,

Answer (score 4):

There is:

- the [Citizen Card](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CitizenCard)
- the [Pass Card](https://www.postoffice.co.uk/identity/pass-card)

These both implement the National "[Proof of Age Standards Scheme](https://www.pass-scheme.org.uk/about-us/)" endorsed by the Home Office and the National Police Chiefs' Council.

Comment: The Pass Card is intended for exactly the kind of age verfication that OP asked. Unlike, say a "gym card" the issuer takes [formal steps](https://postoffice.citizencard.com/requirements-for-a-post-office-pass-card) to verify the identity of the applicant.